# jit thread pool crash

Tags: android, jit

Im developing an Android application and now I am getting a very strange error I have no idea why it happens.
I also found no similar problem in the internet.
My project is also really big and so with this error message I dont really know which code could cause this, that is why here is no code.

crash log:

```
pid: 4228, tid: 4235, name: Jit thread pool  >>> com.application.norm <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc0000000018
    x0  0000000000000014  x1  0000fbd4a757e530  x2  8000000000000003  x3  0000000000000014
    x4  0000fbd4a75e6448  x5  0000000000000009  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  0000000000000127  x9  8a1336e56e6fef71  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000fbd4abe7ac90  x14 ffffffffffffffff  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 000000000000019e  x17 00000000000001a1  x18 0000000000000038  x19 0000fbd4a95fe960
    x20 00000c0000000000  x21 0000fbd4abe86678  x22 0000000000000014  x23 0000fbd4abe77bd0
    x24 0000000000000128  x25 0000fbd4a9fc0828  x26 0000000000000126  x27 0000fbd4abe77bb0
    x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000fbd4a95fe880
    sp  0000fbd4a95fe800  lr  0000fbd4a9ef7090  pc  0000fbd4a9ef70c0

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000002130c0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocationResolver::ConnectSiblings(art::LiveInterval*)+608)
    #01 pc 000000000016cd64  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocationResolver::Resolve(art::ArrayRef<art::HInstruction* const>, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, art::ArrayRef<art::LiveInterval* const>)+884)
    #02 pc 000000000021490c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::RegisterAllocatorLinearScan::AllocateRegisters()+140)
    #03 pc 0000000000209d90  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::AllocateRegisters(art::HGraph*, art::CodeGenerator*, art::PassObserver*, art::RegisterAllocator::Strategy, art::OptimizingCompilerStats*)+640)
    #04 pc 0000000000209558  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::TryCompile(art::ArenaAllocator*, art::ArenaStack*, art::CodeVectorAllocator*, art::DexCompilationUnit const&, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::VariableSizedHandleScope*) const+2120)
    #05 pc 00000000001681fc  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+820)
    #06 pc 000000000010d60c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, bool)+204)
    #07 pc 0000000000309fcc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool)+620)
    #08 pc 000000000030c694  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+644)
    #09 pc 00000000004b0bb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+88)
    #10 pc 00000000004b068c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
    #11 pc 0000000000083114  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #12 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Every time this crash occurs, The following information will be included in the dmesg information

```
Line 780: [ 7.247798] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p12): 1 orphan inode deleted
Line 781: [ 7.253968] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p12): recovery complete
Line 782: [ 7.266940] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p12): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro,nomblk_io_submit
Line 819: [ 7.826534] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p12): Ignoring removed nomblk_io_submit option
```

I don't know if this exception message is related to this crash。
if you know, please help me,
thanks a lot

Comment: Using any reflection, by chance? ... based on an article [here](https://medium.com/@mohamadsamiazar/what-the-hell-is-this-log-b17f07fd2b9) that contains a similar error from `libart.so`, and the author mentions reflection as being a possible cause.

Comment: Thank you for your help。reflection is actually used in the code ` Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");`。The probability of this crash is relatively high。I don't know the connection between the crash and reflection 。What should I do next？Do you have any good suggestions？@ Paul T

Answer (score 0):

In my case (quite a large `Qt`-based project) this was caused by an attempt to use a dangling pointer to an instance of `QObject` derived class.